# Array of floats not getting correct size -- C

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a program that does some image filtering given a BMP file. 
I am given a function that does the filtering for me, but requires specific inputs that I get from `stdin`, and my program needs to put them in the correct format. One of the function inputs needs to be an array of floats. The size of this array is determined by the array width input by the user squared. So an input of 3 would yield an array of size 9 (simulating a matrix. For further reading on what I'm doing, check [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing))).

My program correctly receives the filter width. It correctly computes the array/matrix size value. However, when it comes to initializing an array of floats to put values into, it does this incorrectly.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    int filter_width;
    filter_width = atoi(argv[3]);

    // Initializing variables for the filter weights array
    int filter_matrix_size;
    filter_matrix_size = filter_width*filter_width;
    float filter_weights[filter_matrix_size];
```

For an Filter Width input of 3, I **SHOULD** be getting the following values for my 3 variables here:

Filter Width: 3

Filter Matrix Size: 9

Size of `filter_weights[]` = 9

But when I test my program I'm getting the size of `filter_weights[]` to be 36. I have no idea where this number comes from and it's destroying the image filtering. Am I missing something here?

Comment: sizeof(filter_weights) returns the size of filter_weights in BYTES -- the number of floats in filter_weights times the size in bytes of each float. If I'm correct in recalling that a single-precision floating point number is four bytes long, that would explain where 36 is coming from.

Comment: How are you getting the size? If you're using `sizeof`, that returns the size _in bytes_.

Comment: "when I test my program". Don't tell, show.

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's not necessarily four bytes, but it's common enough that the assumption is reasonable.

Comment: @n.m., ... I did show. Running that code yields an array of floats of size 36...

Comment: @KommanderKitten "Showing" would mean the actual lines of code that printed 36 would be shown in the question text. You _said_ something about the "size of" the array but you don't _show_ how you computed the size.

Comment: @Quentin Good point. I should have said "very often" -- and told OP to try `printf("sizeof(float) == %d", sizeof(float));`

Comment: Code you have shown outputs nothing. It is also incomplete and will not pass compilation. Please look up MCVE.

Comment: @n.m., my question was answered and I've moved on. However, I will definitely look that up and apply it for future questions. Thank you!

Comment: "apply it for future questions" yes, that's basically the idea. Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof` computes the total size of the array, not the number of elements.
Assuming `sizeof(float) == 4` on your system, you then have

```
sizeof(float) == 4
sizeof(float[2]) == 8 (2 * sizeof(float))
sizeof(float[9]) == 36 (9 * sizeof(float))
```

If you want the number of elements you can divide by the size of the first element

```
float arr[N];
(sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]) == N

sizeof arr == (N * sizeof(float))
sizeof arr[0] == sizeof(float)
```

Programmers often define a macro for this:

```
#define LEN(A) (sizeof (A) / sizeof (A)[0])

float arr[N];
LEN(arr) == N
```

though I personally stay away from it as it can be confusing when used with  pointers instead of arrays.

```
float *arr = malloc(/*whatever*/);
LEN(arr) == sizeof(float*)
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(filter_weights)` will be 36, because it contains nine four-byte `float`s. 9 x 4 = 36.

Comment: Ah! Well I see where 36 is coming from now. However, shouldn't `float filter_weights[filter_matrix_size];` still create an array of floats with 9 elements?

Comment: @KommanderKitten That's exactly what it does. And an array of floats with 9 elements comprises 36 bytes of data, which is what sizeof tells you.